# Setting initial values in Form Meta class

Tags: django, metaclass, form-fields

Let's suposse I have the following model:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

I want its form to have an initial value for the field 'name', so it could be:

```
class ExampleForm(forms.ModelForm):
   name = forms.CharField(initial="initial_name")
```

That's good enought for this simple example but in case I have more complex ModelFields (i.e. with overwritten widgets) I'm missing all when re-assigning the field 'name' with the basic `forms.CharField`.

**My question:** Is there a way to set the initials in the Meta class, in the same way the widgets can be? something like...

```
 class ExampleForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         initials = {
             'name': 'initial_name',
         }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the options that I would checkout:

#### Option 1: Provide initial form data when instantiating the form.

This is the most basic way to do it. In your views.py, simply provide the data with the `initial` keyword argument.

**views.py**

```
from forms import ExampleForm

INITIAL_DATA = {'name': 'initial_name'}

def my_view(request):
    ...
    form = ExampleForm(initial=INITIAL_DATA)
    ...
```

Not too tricky. The only downside would be if you use and abuse that form and get tired of passing in the initial data.

#### Option 2 (ideal for your case): Provide the initial data in the `__init__` method of the class.

Forms in Django are designed to accept initial data at instantiation, so you can mess with those values in the `__init__` method. Without testing it, this what I imagine it would look like:

**forms.py**

```
class ExampleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """If no initial data, provide some defaults."""
        initial = kwargs.get('initial', {})
        initial['name'] = 'initial_name'
        kwargs['initial'] = initial
        super(ExampleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

This would be optimal because you can ignore the `initial={...}` in the view code.